# Does China issue treasury bonds too?

Tags: government-debt, debt, bonds, china

The USA is issuing a lot of treasury bonds and investors are buying it.

But does China issue such bonds too?

If yes, then how many such bonds did they issued and who are the largest owners of those debts?

Comment: Have you tried Googling parts of your question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_debt_of_China#:~:text=The%20national%20debt%20(or%20government,to%20about%2048.4%25%20of%20GDP

Comment: Great link, thanks. Yet i'm not clear how much of that debt is in form of treasury bonds.

Comment: Some hints in [this old Forbes article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/peterpham/2018/02/28/who-owns-chinas-bond-market/#7ed0a0944361). By my math the central Chinese government had issued about $2 trillion in bonds as of 2016. It looks like most of that was owned by (domestic?) banks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Biggest foreign owners of China debt?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/39044/biggest-foreign-owners-of-china-debt)