# Biggest foreign owners of China debt?

Tags: debt, international-economics

It is already known that China and Japan are the biggest owners of US debt - about one trillion dollars each.

But who are the biggest owners of China debt? I mean the foreign owners.

Comment: If you are going to ask this separately, I guess you should delete [your other question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/39024/does-china-issue-treasury-bonds-too), lest they be deemed duplicates.

Comment: Sorry I'm not conviced about that. I suggest waiting for more opinions

Comment: Alright, I will just start the process then. (The only non-answered part, who owns the debt is identical.)

Comment: @Giskard this is clearly a duplicate of the second question but shouldn’t this thread be voted as duplicate instead of the original one?

Comment: @1muflon1 There is no rule against voting the earlier question as the duplicate, and I think this one is more concise. But you are free to start a vote here :)